# How to run the selenium in default browser of firefox

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have tried the `FirefoxProfile`, but I received the exception -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space.

Using following code -

```
ProfilesIni prf=new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile=prf.getProfile("default-1453281235998");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://192.168.5.14/ames_1.3.0/login");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUser")).sendKeys("XXX");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtPass")).sendKeys("XXX");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='LOGIN']")).click();
try{
        driver.findElement(By.id("act2")).click();
    }
 catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
 {
 }
driver.findElement(By.id("adminBannerLink_id")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("BGMLink_id")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("BSGMLink_id")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. means your heap space maybe too small. try use java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -jar selenium.jar.

JAVA OPTS see:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: In addition to the answer, if you connect 'JConsole' to your Java application, you can see the usage of your memory divided in heap and non-heap memory. In your case the heap is more important. Check with some minimum and maximum values how much your app needs, and how much it uses to perform good (to perform good, it needs a bit more memory space). JConsole is installed together with your JDK, you can find it in the bin folder